# Display Json data in laravel view with Join tables one as reference table

Tags: arrays, json, laravel

Can someone help? I wanted to display columns from join tables in laravel view. One specific columns has json data.

Table:

##### `ref_code_exam`

| id | description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Exam 1 |
| 2 | Exam 2 |
| 3 | Exam 3 |

##### `ref_appointment`

| id | registry_id | type_of_exam_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 2 |
| 2 | 11 | ["1","2","3"] |

Code in my controller:

```php
$data = $this->data();

$array = array();

foreach ($data as $v) {
    $apptype1[] = $v->type_of_exam_id

    $array[$v->id] = array(
        'type_of_app' => array()
    );

    $type_of_app = DB::table('ref_code_exam')
        ->wherein('id', $apptype1)
        ->get();

    foreach ($type_of_app as $k) {
        array_push($array[$v->id]['type_of_app'], $k->description);
    }
}

return view('transactions.pendapp', ['data' => $data, 'apptype1' => $array])
    ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) -1) * 10);
```

View Controller:

```html
@foreach($data as $students)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
        <td>{{ $students->applicant_no }}</td>
        <td>{{ $students->stud_fname }}</td>
        <td>{{ $students->stud_mname }}</td>
        <td>{{ $students->stud_lname }}</td>
        {{-- <td>{{ $students->description}}</td> --}}
        <td>
            @foreach ($apptype1[$students->id] as $v)
                @for ($m = 0; $m < count($v); $m++)
                    <li>{{ $v[$m] }}</li>
                @endfor
            @endforeach
        </td>
```

However, under type of exam column, its listing all the type of exam description even if it has only one type of exam selected.

Comment: What you get if you do ```<li>{{ $v }}</li>``` ???

Comment: encountered error message like thishtmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: What's this ```["1","2","3"]``` ?? Can you give me a sample of your *object-data* ??

Comment: data save from multiple checkboxes

Comment: ```$m < count($v)``` meaning *count($v)* is the total of checkbox checked, isn't it? Then ```<li>{{ $v[$m] }}</li>``` will show the the checkbox that user check is it? So if user check the three checkbox, It will show ```["1","2","3"]```. What's problem there.